# iPad - UIImageView respond to touch

Tags: ipad, uiimage, xamarin.ios, touch

In MonoTouch how do I get a UIImage or UIImageView to fire off a delegate or something when clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as Dimitris pointed out, you'll want to subclass UIImageView, and also ensure that the userInteractionEnabled flag is set to true.

I should point out that in most cases where people intend to have a UIImageView respond to interaction, these problems can just as easily be fixed by creating a UIButton instance with an image instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to subclass it (the UIImageView) and override one of TouchesBegan, TouchesMoved or TouchesEnded methods, according to what you want to do.